# Is it even possible to implement AutoCompleteMode on TextBox in C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Following this guide: https://youtu.be/vNOEp_23Pa0?t=334

The guy has the following line:

```
Search.txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

Now every time I do it I get a red line only under the AutoCompleteMode next to Search.txt.

With error saying :

```
CS1061  'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'AutoCompleteMode' and no
extension method 'AutoCompleteMode' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
```

Now I've searched everywhere online with no luck.  So is it possible to have autocomplete/database connectivity in C# ?

This is my first application so huge beginner. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. There's a bunch of third party controls (including WPF Toolkit) which implement an autocomplete textbox.

A non-third party approach that many use involve taking the `ComboBox` and using it's autocomplete feature. You can override the style so that it looks and feels like a textbox, so this is a quick-and-dirty way to do it.

The other approach (which I feel is the more orthodox way) is to add an adorner containing the autocomplete functionality, to the textbox. It's a bit more work, but you can really style it to your heart's content. I've used this approach, because I often need to present an autocomplete dropdown as the user types, then tokenize the input, and present the autocomplete again as the user keeps on typing. Kind of like how JIRA does it. This sort of functionality is too advanced for a simple combobox.  You'll probably find that most of the third party controls follow the adorner pattern, or something similar to that approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would of thought that a language so established and sophisticated like C# will have a built in one included easily. I tried looking at WPF Toolkit but it didn't work at all. I'm probably doing it wrong, do you have a detailed very beginner guide for it? Using the ComboBox feature and overriding it will be something I will look into. Thanks again for the answer, hopefully this language is worth fully learning.

Comment: Looking at a ComboBox guide now and the user as additional methods like AutoCompleteMode...AutoCompleteSource, looking at mine, I can't find any like that. On all Properties section I'm missing AutoCompletemode etc. Are they 3rd party libraries I have to import?

Comment: You need to set `IsEditable` to true, and `IsTextSearchEnabled` to true. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - after that, just set the `ItemsSource` to point to the autocomplete list.

Comment: Last final question(promise) Is there a way to remove the drop down menu button from Combo Boxes? - The little down arrow.

Comment: You can, but will require delving a bit deeper into the XAML of the combo box. If you have Expression Blend, you can extract the content template and manage the modification pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I might need more later though so I will keep messaging you if that's okay with you :)

Answer (score 0):

The WPF textbox `System.Windows.Controls.Textbox` does not have AutoCompleteMode. I didn't check the video, but I suspect that they are using the WinForms textbox `System.Windows.Forms.Textbox`, which does.

Comment: The guy used this line : Search.txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; Isn't that a Controls.Textbox package only? I have Form.Textbox including but It still brings up errors.